# How to set the state of a component with the information obtained from a promise to avoid memory leaks in react

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, state

Where should I set the state of the component with the information gotten from a resolved promise in a way that if the component is unmounted before the last two actions are done it doesn't cause a memory leak?

```
class Schedule extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      someKey: ''
    };
  }

  someMethod = () => {
    axios.get('some-url')
    .then((response) => {
      setState({someKey: response})
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <button onClick={this.someMethod}>Click Me</button>
    )
  }

}

export Schedule
```

If I leave the page before the new state is set if gives me this error:

'Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.'

How do I handle this?

Comment: Please show where you call `someMethod`

Comment: done @Vencovsky

Comment: are you using `this.setState`?

Comment: You could add a `Set` as a static variable to `Schedule` class, add `this` to the set in `constructor`, and remove `this` from the set in `componentWillUnmount()`, then make sure that the set has `this` each time you call `setState()` from a promise resolution.

Answer (score 1):

In general to handle API calls I would recommend you some app state management F.E Redux / MobX. But for simple usecase you can try go with:

```
class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.isMounted = false;

        this.state = {
          someKey: []
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.isMounted = true;
      }

      someMethod = () => {
        axios.get("some_url").then(res => {
          if (this.isMounted) {
            this.setState({
              someKey: res
            });
          }
        });
      };

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.isMounted = false;
      }

      render() {
        ...
      }
    }
```

Comment: Very similar to what I suggested in comments :) I like this better than my suggestion actually.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also cancel the axios request.

```js
class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.source = axios.CancelToken.source();

        this.state = {
          someKey: []
        };
      }

      someMethod = () => {
        axios.get("some_url"{ cancelToken: this.source.token }).then(res => {
            this.setState({
              someKey: res
            });
        })
        // catch axios cancel error, we don't want to show it
        .catch(err => {

          // if it's not an axios cancel error, we may want to re-throw the error (depending on the app structure)
          if(!err.name === 'Cancel') {
            throw err;
          }
        });
      };

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.source.cancel('Cancel message');
      }

      render() {
        ...
      }
    }
```

https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

Comment: You'll probably want to catch the cancellation in an empty `.catch(() => {})` at least so it does not produce an uncaught promise rejection (or if error handling is already being done, integrate it to differentiate between bad responses and cancellations).

Comment: Right, I edited my response to include your remark.